# Gracefully Stopping Docker Containers

Tags: docker, signals, dockerfile, tcsh

I'm having some trouble to understand how I can do some cleanup when the container is stopped.

To make it easier, I prepared a sample to reproduce the problem.

Here are the contents of my files:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM opensuse:latest

# Install tcsh (non-interactive mode)
RUN zypper -n in tcsh

# Create user
RUN useradd -ms /bin/tcsh dummyuser

# Set the user
USER dummyuser

# Change Working Dir
WORKDIR /home/dummyuser

# Copy entrypoint script
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh $HOME

# Starter Script
ENTRYPOINT ["./docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

**docker-entrypoint.sh**

```
#!/bin/tcsh

echo "Starting"

onintr cleanup

# Running something in foreground, otherwise the container will stop
while (1)
   sleep 1000
end
exit 0

cleanup:
   onintr -
   echo "cleanup on going"
   exit 0
```

Make `docker-entrypoint.sh` executable:

```
chmod 744 docker-entrypoint.sh
```

Build the image:

```
docker build -t my-dummy-img .
```

Notice that I'm using `tcsh` shell.

If you take a look at the `docker-entrypoint.sh` you can see that I'm waiting to cath the interrupt (`onintr cleanup`) and call a cleanup method.

Now, these are the commands I run:

```
mstack/dummy-project> docker run --name my-service -ti -d my-dummy-img ps -eaf
da1dc21281a58e384f2ff34aa49a82019214e204e6d7a77ff54e8c96e005f913
mstack/dummy-project> docker logs my-service
Starting
mstack/dummy-project> docker stop my-service
my-service
mstack/dummy-project> docker logs my-service
Starting
mstack/dummy-project>
```

Here is the problem, I would expect that after the second `docker logs my-service` the output would be:

```
Starting
cleanup on going
```

Instead of only

```
Starting
```

Because docker is supposed to send a signal when stopping...

On the other hand, if I run:

`docker run --name my-service-attached -ti my-dummy-img ps -eaf`

And hit `CTRL+C`, I can see the expected output.

What am I missing here? I hope the question is clear enough.

BTW, I used the following to articles as guideline:

[Gracefully Stopping Docker Containers](https://www.ctl.io/developers/blog/post/gracefully-stopping-docker-containers/)

[Trapping signals in Docker containers](https://medium.com/@gchudnov/trapping-signals-in-docker-containers-7a57fdda7d86#.qxvh1vb1e)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally solved the problem.

[Tcsh shell doesn't receive most of the signals like SIGTERM](http://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/versus/csh.whynot) which is the signal sent by docker when stopping the container.

So I changed the script to use bash shell and whenever I want to run a tcsh command I just do it like this:

```
/bin/tcsh ./my-command
```

So, my **docker-entrypoint.sh** is like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# SIGTERM-handler this funciton will be executed when the container receives the SIGTERM signal (when stopping)
term_handler(){
   echo "***Stopping"
   /bin/tcsh ./my-cleanup-command
   exit 0
}

# Setup signal handlers
trap 'term_handler' SIGTERM

echo "***Starting"
/bin/tcsh ./my-command

# Running something in foreground, otherwise the container will stop
while true
do
   #sleep 1000 - Doesn't work with sleep. Not sure why.
   tail -f /dev/null & wait ${!}
done
```

Comment: Could you explain this in details please? `tail -f /dev/null & wait ${!}`

Comment: `tail -f /dev/null &` runs the tail command in the background, and then `wait ${!}` waits for it to finish. `tail -f /dev/null` or `sleep 1000` is *not* good enough, as they block the signal processing. `wait`, on the contrary, is interruptible.

Answer (score 1):

This may be because you launch it in detached mode: [see documentation](http://www.tcsh.org/tcsh.html/Builtin_commands.html).

> onintr is ignored if the shell is running detached

You will have to find alternative, like using bash and trap [as seen here](https://www.ctl.io/developers/blog/post/gracefully-stopping-docker-containers/)

Answer (score 1):

I had a simple trapping bash script that ran the `main` function that called all the other programs, and `shutdown` function to run the scripts to shut it down gracefully:

```
trap "shutdown" SIGTERM

main
```

I couldn't get Docker to trigger the shutdown function when stopping the container. Adding exec before the command, using tini as init, changing the STOPSIGNAL did not help it. The reason is because the programs `main` ran did not return the control.

Adding `& wait` to the end makes it work fine:

```
trap "shutdown" SIGTERM

main & wait
```